# Tomcat Rewrite Rules Angular 5 Application?

Tags: angular, tomcat, deployment, url-rewriting

I have developed an application containing `Routing` in Angular 5 and I have built it with `ng build --base-href /myApp/ --prod`. Now I want to deploy it on a tomcat server running local on my Laptop.

The Problem is, that whenever i reload a page of my application in the browser, I get the error:

> 404 The requested resource is not available

I have searched in the internet for solving strategies, but nothing that I have found helped me. I am pretty sure that I have to declare some `Rewrite rules` but I have no Idea how they should look like and where I have to declare them.

Somebody who have an idea how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The application deep links will not work without the redirect rule on the server. All the deep links have to redirect to the application `index.html` by the server.

To setup the tomcat to redirect any deep links -

1. Configure the RewriteValve in server.xml
2. Write the rewrite rule in rewrite.config

**1. Configure the RewriteValve in server.xml**

Edit the ~/conf/server.xml to add the below Valve inside the Host section as below –

```
...
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />

...
      </Host>
...
```

**2. Write the rewrite rule in rewrite.config**

Create directory structure – ~/conf/Catalina/localhost/ and create the rewrite.config file inside it with the below content. Note - here I am considering `/myApp` as the context path of the application.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/myApp/(.*) /myApp/index.html
```

After setting this up restart the tomcat server and you can hit the deep links of the application which will route to the correct components inside the angular application.

You can refer to [this post](http://codedumpster.nithinbiliya.com/deep-linking-issue-angular-application-tomcat-server/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a web.xml entry in the WEB-INF directory to redirect all unknown URLs to your default index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
    <display-name>My Angular Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/index.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>410</error-code>
        <location>/index.html</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the user is getting 404s when he shouldn't be (actual, non-home page content is wanted), not how to suppress 404s by routing them to the home page.